# Aggregating multiple groups at certain condition that could be true at one of them

Tags: spring-integration

I have a line that call two webservice for it

and increment a global counter for the responses at interceptor for each aggregator

```
request -> success -> completedAggreator ( release strategy if  doneCondition())

request -> fail-> FailAggregator ( release strategy if doneCondition())

doneCondition(){
    numberOfResponse = line * 2
}
```

the problem is the last response may arrive to one of the aggregator and released successfully but the other aggregator still waiting as it didn't receive that last response to validate on release condition

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a task for the Scatter-Gather: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather.

Otherwise it’s not clear why do you need two aggregators, meanwhile a group is based on the correlation independently of the execution result.

Please, explain your business task. Right now it’s not clear what you try to do.